# Bollinger Journal translation of a few pages

Tags: translation

I found a journal whose earliest date appears to be the 1821.  It appears to be written in Sutterlin text. Could you help translate a few pages?  The family name is Bollinger.

Thank you,
Bonnie

[image: Bollinger Journal, 17 September 1823]

Comment: **To close voters:** Community had not changed their opinion on this: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/579/are-questions-on-reading-of-old-handwritings-on-topic and https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/sind-fragen-%c3%bcber-die-entschl%c3%bcsselung-von-schriften-auch-handschriften-on-topic

Answer (score 3):

The side note could read something like this:

> Könnte ich dein Glück in Blumen winden
>   Gewiß du solltest glücklich sein,
>   Ich wollt nichts als Kränze winden
>   Und alles gute mit hinein

Answer (score 2):

An initial try:

> Zu Andrer Glück sein eignes finden
>
> Ist dieses Lebens Seligkeit
>
> Und andrer Menschen Wohlfahrt gründen
>
> Schafft göttlich Zufriedenheit
>
> Berlin, 17. September 1823
>
> Von deinem treuen Freund
>
> F.W. Dürr

*To find your own happiness in that of others*

*Is this life's blessedness*

*And founding other humans' welfare*

*creates divine contentedness*

The margin text (left, vertical) is extremely hard to read but could mean something like

> **Symbol**
>
> Könnte ich dein Glück in Blumen (?schmücken?)

Rest of the text in the margin doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: You have dropped an *e* from «Seeligkeit». ☺ The last line is rather «gz. von dein treuen Freund». The «Symbol» may read as follows: «Könnte ich dein Glück in Blumen winden / Gewiss du sollst glücklich sein / Ich wollt nichts als Kränze winden / und alles gute mit sinnen».

Comment: "Zu And**e**rer Glück..."?

Comment: @IQV ja, es steht "Anderer" mit zwei "e"